# phaser - How to zoom around point of focus (mouse or pinch)

Tags: game-engine, phaser-framework

I want that my phaser world scales at the point where my mouse pointer is (or between 2 fingers/pinch). Per default, phaser scales/zooms around the top left corner.

Here is an example (but not for phaser) that shows what exactly I want to achive: https://cloudup.com/blog/how-we-made-zoom-on-mobile-using-css3-and-js

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See these examples of working implementations:

- http://test.xapient.net/phaser/springtest/indexzoom.html (a and o)

Comment: Link no longer works. This is why posting code, instead of just links is preferred on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To scale a group of items based on a the clicked point.

Capture the start position of the group (x,y) and the mouse click point:

```
startPosX = this.position.x;
startPosY = this.position.y;

clickX = pointer.x;
clickY = pointer.y;
```

Perform the scale of the group:

```
var tweenScale = game.add.tween(this.scale).to( { x: 2, y: 2 }, 10,
                    Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true, 0, 0, false);
```

On scale complete, tween back to mouse click location:

```
tweenScale.onComplete.add(function() {                  
    var u = ((1-this.scale.x) * clickX) + startPosX;
    var v = ((1-this.scale.y) * clickY) + startPosY;

    game.add.tween(this.position)
        .to({ x: this.position.x + u, y: this.position.y + v}, 10, 
           Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true, 0, 0, false );
}, this);
```

I added `startPosX` to get `u` (and `v` respectively) to account for the location of the original starting point of the group or else it would be off, by that amount.  I'm sure there are different ways to approach the tween chaining, but the calculations for `u` and `v` are what's important.

Used this answer to derive the basic calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344716/1956540